# optional parameter checking in where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a bunch of report parameters and as a result my criteria checking first checks if parameter value is null and if not compares it with a column value .

```
        (@dateStart IS NULL OR @dateStart <= BELGE.AccDate)
        AND (@dateEnd IS NULL OR @dateEnd >= BELGE.AccDate)
        AND (@CompanyId IS NULL OR @CompanyId = hrktlr.CompanyId)
        AND ((@onKayitlarDahil = 1 and hrktlr.StatusCode in ('M', 'O')) 
                OR (@onKayitlarDahil = 0 AND hrktlr.StatusCode = 'M'))
        AND (@BizPartnerId IS NULL or CK.BizPartnerId = @BizPartnerId)
        AND (@BizPartnerKodStart is null or @BizPartnerKodStart = '' or @BizPartnerKodStart <= CK.BizPartnerKod)
        AND (@BizPartnerKodEnd is null or @BizPartnerKodEnd = '' or @BizPartnerKodEnd >= CK.BizPartnerKod)
        AND (@BizPartnerType is null or @BizPartnerType=CK.BizPartnerType)
```

this is great for a maintainable sql query, but the problem is that Sql Query Optimizer prepares itself for the worst case I guess, and  index usage is bad. For example when I pass in BizPartnerId and thus avoid BizPartnerId is null check, query runs a 100 times faster.
So if I keep going with this approach are there any pointers that you can recommend for Query Planner to help increase query performance.

Any viable alternatives to optional parameter checking?

Comment: What if you replace *@BizPartnerId IS NULL* with **@BizPartnerId=-1**

Comment: its type is uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Is that inside of a stored procedure, or just a plain query? Is it precompiled? I've used this technique for quite a long time now, and I 've never had an issue even with very large amounts of data (although I have to say that I've since changed to on-demand generated queries with great effect).

Comment: I use this approach both in stored procedures and also with plain queries. This sample one has declare parameters section first, and setting of the parameter values then the query execution.

Comment: Also, does the query work well if you *remove* one of the conditions altogether? It might very well be that your indices aren't actually well built for this kind of query.

Comment: @Luaan yes, removing null checking helps improve the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop sql server form saving a sub optimal query plan you can use the option WITH RECOMPILE. The query plan will be recalculated each time you run the query.

Comment: +1 for with recompile... and -1 for trying to outsmart the optimizer with the index hint (which is not applicable in this case anyway as you do not know whick paramters are coming for this query).

Comment: Index hint would be very complex, I dont know if it is possible but Index hint should have a case statement in it so that we can recommend the right index.

Comment: recompile seems to help. My stored procedures are created with this option but I have skipped adding this hint on plain queries. Adding it helps a lot.

Comment: @hazimdikenli Yes, this helps a lot. However, be aware that this doesn't scale too well - it's great when you're only calling it once per second, but as you get to eg. 10 or 100 per second (common for a web frontend), you're in trouble - you're overloading the server with tons of recompiles. If that's your case, you might have to use a different approach, eg. using a few different queries optimized for some cases (one reason why you don't use the "advanced search" method for "simple search") or using dynamic SQL (application-side or server-side, whatever suits you best).

Comment: @Luaan you are right, a solution can be to make a sp which chooses which second sp to call based on the given parameters.

Comment: @Luaan this queries are some form of predefined reports, and they are not executed very often. I dont know how often maybe once a minute.

Comment: @hazimdikenli Yeah, that's pretty much the best case for `with recompile`. It can use the best indices etc. Of course, the benefits over dynamic SQL are pretty slim in that case (after all, one of the reasons not to use dynamic SQL is to *avoid* recompilation), but if you want the code in the DB, go ahead. The only thing to be affraid of is someone copying your query and using the principles where they don't apply, but you can't really avoid that :D